# Is a tiny dinner okay?

Tags: food

My staple is Matta rice as a native of India. I eat the most at lunch. I regularly go 9 hours between lunch and dinner with a coffee in between, which I cannot do with any other food.

I recently started eating half as much as a belly-full for dinner. I noticed some weight loss, no loss of energy and slightly better sleep. Is this okay to sustain or will I lose out on nutrition which can be gained only by dinner? I believe big dinners help replenish energy reserves of those who are really active but I work out at home 3-4 times a week.

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is weight loss, your aim should be to consume lesser calories than you spend. Regarding the gap between dinner and lunch, it's a bit too long. Why don't you break your lunch into 2 parts? That way, your system wouldn't starve for 9 hours and you won't end up eating tons during dinner.

Eating small dinner is fine, if you were not active during the evening. Also, eating right is very necessary when it comes to attaining any goal.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46353/discussion-on-answer-by-xcodezone-is-a-tiny-dinner-okay).

Comment: Also, please refrain from attacks in comments. Comments are intended to refine/clarify questions and answers, not attack positions.

Answer (score -3):

Most studies have shown meal timing isn't relevant in terms of weight gain. At the end of the day of course- it just matters on the calories from the specific macronutrients you are eating.

That being the case, its probably better to eat the majority of your food during a time you are generally active, or right after a workout, just so you get the energy from the food. The reason you are losing weight is because you aren't eating enough, it has nothing to do with when you eat.

Do not worry about your meal timing, just make sure you are eating enough for whatever goals you have in mind ( losing weight, gaining weight). Try to schedule some meals around the times you will workout or do something relatively active, since it might give you a boost of energy.

Edit:

See

http://nutritionreviews.oxfordjournals.org/content/73/2/69
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19943985

The idea that increased meal frequency contributes to any noticeable caloric loss and thus leading to potential extra weight loss has been debunked and has never been proven by any scientific studies. Please feel free to comment a study that says otherwise, however please make sure it has references.

Comment: Why downvote? Can anyone provide any evidence to counter any of the points I made? If so I will gladly change my stance